# Using regex to replace characters between two strings while ignoring html tags and new line breaks

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to redact health information from emails that are loaded into a string variable by replacing characters with █. The emails in question need content in between the words "health issues?" and "Have you worked" replaced but ignoring anything that appears in tags. Additionally lines often are wrapped with with = signs, and those new line, spaces, and = signs can occur right in the middle of a tag, and they can also occur in the middle of the strings used to identify the start and end.

Example:

```
(More content)
.....have any health issues? We currently do not have any health issues</sp=
an></li>
 <li id=3D"m_-622133557606915713yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1515713539439_17326" styl=
e=3D"margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;vertical-align:middle;line-height:15pt;co=
lor:black"><span id=3D"m_-622133557606915713yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1515713539439=
_17327" style=3D"font-family:Arial;font-size:11.0pt">Some more text. 
Have
     you worked.....(more content)
```

I am figuring there is a way to do this in javascript using one or more regular expressions, but I am at a loss to see how.

The desired result would look like:

```
(More content)
.....have any health issues?███████████████████████████████████████████</sp=
an></li>
 <li id=3D"m_-622133557606915713yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1515713539439_17326" styl=
e=3D"margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;vertical-align:middle;line-height:15pt;co=
lor:black"><span id=3D"m_-622133557606915713yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1515713539439=
_17327" style=3D"font-family:Arial;font-size:11.0pt">███████████████
Have
     you worked.....(more content)
```

Comment: There wouldn't be a bulletproof regex here but `(health issues\?)((?!<\S)[\s\S])+` can be helpful. Try it here https://regex101.com/r/UoxBp7/1/

Comment: Close, but it wouldn't capture text after html tags, but before the "Have you worked" part. I edited the example to show. Also, not sure how to make it replace the characters.

Comment: Did you find the answer helpful? otherwise I could improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two `replace` methods to solve this problem. The first one matches every thing from `health issues?` to `Have you worked` captured into three capturing groups. We are interested in second capturing group:

```
(health issues\?)([\s\S]*?)(Have\s+you\s+worked)
                  ^^^^^^^^
```

We run our second `replace` method on this captured group and substitutes each character outside of tags with a `█`. This is the regex:

```
(<\/?\w[^<>]*>)|[\s\S]
```

We need to keep first capturing group (they are probably HTML tags) and replace the other side of alternation (`[\s\S]`) with the mentioned character.

**Disclaimer: this is not bulletproof as regex shouldn't be used to parse HTML tags.**

Demo:

```js
var str = `(More content)
.....have any health issues? We currently do not have any health issues</sp=
an></li>
 <li id=3D"m_-622133557606915713yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1515713539439_17326" styl=
e=3D"margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;vertical-align:middle;line-height:15pt;co=
lor:black"><span id=3D"m_-622133557606915713yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1515713539439=
_17327" style=3D"font-family:Arial;font-size:11.0pt">Some more text. 
Have
     you worked.....(more content)`;

console.log(str.replace(/(health issues\?)([\s\S]*?)(Have\s+you\s+worked)/, function(match, $1, $2, $3) {
    return $1 + $2.replace(/(<\/?\w[^<>]*>)|[\s\S]/g, function(match, $1) {
        return $1 ? $1 : '█';
    }) + $3;
}));
```

Comment: Great. I just made one change as I wanted to preserve line endings, so for the second replace, I made [\s\S] be [\ \S]. I learned some regex from this! Thanks.